# Centering artboard view on layer contents on huge bitmap

Tags: interface, navigation, photoshop

I'm working on a very large (35,000 x 35,000 pixel) image in photoshop CS 2018. I have 1000's of layers, many of them with small content (~ 200 x 200 pixels, e.g. bitmap text 20-50 words).

Because there's so much on this canvas, I'm having hard time finding the layer on the image! I can find the layer easily in the layer palette - there's hierarchical organization there - but there's no way that I can find to have PS automatically center my view on the part of the image where the layer content is.

If I zoom out, I can't see the layer because it's too small.

Any tips of how to more easily jump between different parts of such a huge image? Or how to locate layers quickly?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help? The first function will draw guides in the centre of the active layer bounding box so you could easily locate it in the canvas, the second will remove all the guides. Save those as .jsx files in Photoshop/Presets/Scripts folder and after PS restart they will be available in File > Scripts menu (and you can assign them to hotkeys).

The first one:

```
function main() {

    try {
        var l = activeDocument.activeLayer
    } catch (e) {
        return false //no active layer
    }

    var b = l.bounds


    if (b[0] === b[1] === b[2] === b[3]) {
        alert('Looks like the layer "' + l.name + '" is empty');
        return false //layer is empty
    }

    // set to pixels;
    var originalRulerUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
    app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

    var ref = new ActionReference();
    ref.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID("Dcmn"), charIDToTypeID("Ordn"), charIDToTypeID("Trgt"));
    var applicationDesc = executeActionGet(ref);
    var theH = applicationDesc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID("rulerOriginH")) / 65536;
    var theV = applicationDesc.getInteger(stringIDToTypeID("rulerOriginV")) / 65536;
    // reset;

    var halfV = b[1] + (b[3] - b[1]) / 2 - theV;
    var halfH = b[0] + (b[2] - b[0]) / 2 - theH;

    activeDocument.guides.add(Direction.HORIZONTAL, new UnitValue(halfV, app.activeDocument.width.unit));
    activeDocument.guides.add(Direction.VERTICAL, new UnitValue(halfH, app.activeDocument.width.unit));

    app.preferences.rulerUnits = originalRulerUnits;

}
main()
```

and the second one:

```
function main() {
    var idDlt = charIDToTypeID("Dlt ");
    var desc276 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
    var ref184 = new ActionReference();
    var idGd = charIDToTypeID("Gd  ");
    var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID("Ordn");
    var idAl = charIDToTypeID("Al  ");
    ref184.putEnumerated(idGd, idOrdn, idAl);
    desc276.putReference(idnull, ref184);
    executeAction(idDlt, desc276, DialogModes.NO);
}
main()
```

Comment: Fantastic. You, sir, are a scholar and a gentleman! This works wonderfully. If you're wondering why I was looking for this: [Sanctuary Moon Discs](http://www.sanctuaryproject.eu/#sample)